# Auto-Add SVN command line with whitespace

Tags: linux, svn, shell, command-line

I have an SVN repository. I have a shell/bash script that's designed to automatically add all unversioned files to the repository. It looks like this:

```
 svn status | grep '^?' | sed 's/^.* /svn add /' | bash;
```

Which works perfectly, except for when one of my new files has whitespace in the filename. How can I modify this command to deal with that?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

To avoid quoting issues here, you should avoid the shell call altogether and use xargs instead, which will also speed up the process:

```
svn status | grep '^?' | sed -e 's/^? *//' | xargs --no-run-if-empty -d '\n' svn add
```

This will handle most special characters, but *not* work to escape newlines, but since these are the record separator for svn status and grep, you won't get much better than that anyway.

Comment: when I try this I get a 'svn: Not enough arguments provided' error.

Comment: Does adding a --no-run-if-empty between xargs and -d fix it?

Comment: Different error this time. It seems to be having a problem going into subdirectories with this (I have a folder named "Class Files" and it gives the error "svn: '?      Class Files' is not a working copy;
svn: Can't open file '?      Class Files/.svn/entries': No such file or directory"

Comment: Oh, yes. Naturally, the '?' needs to be removed. Edited.

Comment: Ok, this works. Now I need to do the same thing for deleting. I changed the "?" to "!" and the "add" to "delete", and it works, but then after deleting the file it ALSO says "svn filename does not exist". This isn't a huge issue because it still works, but can it be fixed to not show this extra output?

Comment: @Jordan: Best to think about the issue for a moment, have a look at the outputs of xargs echo, try some solutions and then formulate a new question.

Answer (score 3):

Strange that you use a script because `svn add --force .` can do this alone:

```
> svn status
?       INSTALL
?       trunk/INSTALL
?         trunk/INSTALL WITH SPACE
> svn add --force .
A         trunk/INSTALL
A         INSTALL
A         trunk/INSTALL WITH SPACE
```

No more fuss with whitespace :-)

Comment: this is also giving me the error: "svn: Not enough arguments provided"

Comment: Did you eventually ommit the last `.`?

Comment: I've put it into the text also.

Answer (score 1):

Basically,

```
echo -e "? a b c'd'\n? b a" | sed -e "s/'/'\\\\''/g" -e "s/^. /svn add '/" -e 's/$/'\''/'
```

should work.

This `echo` command is for simulating the "worst case output" of `svn status`. Thus you must replace the complete `echo` command with `svn status | grep '^?'`. IOW, you get

```
svn status | grep '^?' | sed -e "s/'/'\\\\''/g" -e "s/^. /svn add '/" -e 's/$/'\''/' | bash
```

Explanation: If you put all filenames in `'`...`'`, you only have to watch for `'`s in the filenames. You replace them by `'\''`, terminating the string, inserting a raw `'` and restarting a new string.

In order to do so, you replace each and every `'` with `'\''`, and afterwards, you put the filename in `'...'`.

So a file name `a b c'd'` gets to the components `'a b c'`, `\'`, `'d'` and `\'`, so it is `'a b c'\''d'\'`. The code above adds an empty `''`, but that doesn't hurt.

Comment: sorry, I'm not quite sure what the proper syntax is with the "echo" replaced by "svn status | grep '^?'". I tried:  svn status | grep '^?' -e "? a b c'd'\n? b a" | sed -e "s/'/'\\\\''/g" -e "s/^. /svn add '/" -e 's/$/'\''/' but it doesn't work

Comment: Of course not, sorry. I meant "the complete `echo` command"... edited my answer.

Comment: Just like with the other answer (above), I get a different error this time. It seems to be having a problem going into subdirectories with this (I have a folder named "Class Files" and it gives the error "svn: '? Class Files' is not a working copy; svn: Can't open file '? Class Files/.svn/entries': No such file or directory"

Answer (score 0):

This should work for whitespace:

```
svn status | grep '^?' | sed 's/^.* \(.*\)$/svn add "\1"/' | bash;
```

However you'll still have issues with quotes and other characters.